# Real Analysis Proof Question

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the function
$$
g(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll} x^3,&\ x\in\mathbb{Q},\\ 0,&\ x\not\in\mathbb{Q}.\end{array} \right.
$$

Prove that for all $a\in\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\},$ $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$ does not exist (as a real number).

Comment: Done! Anything else?

Comment: Nope, nothing else. How do you go about rigorously proving this? @JoséCarlosSantos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a\in\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}$, let $(x_n)$ be a sequence of rational numbers with $x_n \to a$ and let $(y_n)$ be a sequence of irrational numbers with $y_n \to a$.

Then $g(x_n) =x_n^3 \to a^3$ and $g(y_n)=0 \to 0$.

Conclusion ?